# MySQL SQL Sort on certain words within a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a field in my table which contains categories data eg

```
Computer > Mouse
Computer > Keyboard
Archived Game > Strategy
PS3 > Game > sports
```

when I pull them out of the table I strip all but the last word using:

```
$category = trim(substr($databack20[main_category], strrpos($databack20[main_category], '>') + 1));
```

Which works perfectly.

I need to pull these out of the table, in name order

So currently I get:

```
Archived Game > Strategy
Computer > Keyboard
Computer > Mouse
PS3 > Game > Sports
```

But the order I need is:

```
Keyboard
Mouse
Sports
Strategy
```

Is there a way to do this within the query? If so how, if not is there another way?

Comment: Don't store these values as concatenated strings in one field.  It's going to cause you pain forever.  Look at EntityAttributeValue tables or some other 1:many relationship.

Comment: Wrap your current results in a select that contains the order by, or use the same logic in the order by.  Overall though use a parent child relationship if it's not too late to change design.

Comment: @Dems I don't have a choice unfortunately, thats how they come to me from an API feed - xQbert, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @Dems: EAV? Not obviously applicable in this case, and an anti-pattern in general.

Comment: @MarkBannister - `In software engineering, an anti-pattern (or antipattern) is a pattern that may be commonly used but is ineffective and/or counterproductive in practice.`  EAV has it's problems, but can be (and often has been for me) useful if used for in a specifically constrained set of functionality.

Comment: @Dems: It is counterproductive if used outside the area where it is the only viable option - ie. in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I do agree with the answers, you should split out the string into separate fields, you can sort it as you'd like, although performance will not be very good.   Try this

```
ORDER BY LCASE(RIGHT(main_category, LOCATE('>', REVERSE(main_category) ) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  <your current query>
)
  AS data
ORDER BY
  field_name_1,
  field_name_2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a field in my table which contains categories data eg

this is what you are doing wrong.
the catalog hierarchy should be implemented using more intelligent design.

The very basic rule of the database design is that data in the fields should be *atomic*, i.e. represent only one matter.
Mixing matters will lead you to the site malfunction pretty soon.

You have to store each catalog node in a separate field. Thus you'll be able to order by whatever level nodes. You may also wish to add a "parent" field, to link a node with a parent one.

Comment: -1 Not a bad suggestion in general, but not applicable in this case - see the comments on the question.

Comment: I know them already without reading. A laziness is a mother of inventions of excuses ;)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do such sort in pure SQL, I think you have better to use php sorting functions such as [`sort`](http://fr.php.net/sort), [`usort`](http://fr.php.net/usort) to sort the list the way you want.

Comment: order by works with that "Computer > A" and "PS3 > B", you can sort by the stuff after the >, without using some RDBM specific functions?

Comment: The OP already has a query that extracts the values that it needs to be ordered by.  Either use the query as a sub-query and ORDER BY that field's alias [My Answer], or just ORDER BY that field's code [Sparky's answer].

Comment: last time I have checked LEFT RIGHT LCASE wasn't in the SQL standards!

Comment: @RageZ: You said pure SQL, not ANSI standard SQL. All of those functions are available in MySQL's dialect of SQL.